# Error :- Could not find databinding-compiler.jar

Tags: android, data-binding, androidx

- Gradle version 3.4.1
- Gradle wrapper gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
- Android Studio 3.4.1

After I add this section to my `app.gradle`:

```
dataBinding {
  enabled = true
 }
```

my project is giving an error when building. The error is:

```
Could not find databinding-compiler.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler/3.4.1/databinding-compiler-3.4.1.jar
```

[app.gradle p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v8uk.png)

[app.gradle p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5J99.png)

[app.gradle p4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCWLd.png)

[project.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmml6.png)

[gradle.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BpQe.png)

[gradle-wrapper.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv9tS.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE8xt.png)

Answer (score 2):

Go to

**Tools** -> **SDK Manager** -> **SDK Tools** -> Then check the **Support Repository** and hit **Ok**

> The Support repository will be downloaded. Then try syncing the project.

[image: Check this screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

i was have this problem and as [Santanu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56291374/6551200) said (thanks for help) i go to **Tools** -> **SDK Manager** -> **SDK Tools**
but there wasn`t **Support Repository** exists

but **Android Emulator** and **Android SDK Platform-Tools** and **Documentation for Android SDK** was need update so i just click check box and alert showing 'need update'

[image]

so i click update and they was updated and Then try syncing the project and error gone and problem was fixed